# How to show dropup-menu content completely when scroll bar is in effect?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, bootstrap-4, scrollbar

I am working on a [website](http://jsfiddle.net/pkg4zh68/15/embedded/result) in which I want to show dropup-menu content completely when scroll bar is in effect.

At this moment, the dropup-menu content doesn't show up completely when we are scrolling up/down.

The css code which I have used in order to show the scroll bar is:

```
.dropdowns
{
  overflow-y:auto;
  height: 100px;
}
```

The html code which I have used in order to make the button is:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>

    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of the problem which I am facing:

[image]

As shown above, the dropup menu doesn't seem to have the full content. It is missing Action text.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the css codes so that I can see the complete dropup content when scroll up/down.

As stated above in the screenshot, dropup content is getting cut when scrolling up/down.

**Edit 1:** I want the scrollbar (having list of buttons) at the bottom to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry I didn't notice the scroll bar

Try to add something like this :

```
.btn-group.show {
  position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pkg4zh68/14/

Comment: Although it’s working but it seems like the browser movement is getting effected deeply.

Comment: Can you explain better, what is expected?

Comment: Hi, This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pkg4zh68/15/embedded/result in my question. If I add your changes, the browser movement is going anywhere.

Comment: Are you around ?